# Prove $f(y)=\max_Z y'Az$ is a continuous function of $y\in Y$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I was wondering how to prove the continuity of a optimized function over their parameters. Above is an example.

Comment: This is a special case of the Theorem of the Maximum.  It has important applications in microeconomic theory.  You will need to assume that the set of maximizers, considered as a function of the parameter $y$ is compact valued.  Then the proof uses the upper and lower semi-continuity of the set of maximizers.

Answer (score 1):

> **Proposition**: Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $Z$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Then, the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(y)=\max_{z\in Z}y^{\intercal}Az$ is continuous.

*Proof.* To establish this, note that for any two vectors $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$,
\begin{multline*}
\left|f(y_{1})-f(y_{2})\right|\leq\max_{z\in Z}\left|y_{1}^{\intercal}Az-y_{2}^{\intercal}Az\right|=\max_{z\in Z}\left|\left(y_{1}-y_{2}\right)^{\intercal}Az\right|\\
=\max_{z\in Z}\left|\left\langle Az,y_{1}-y_{2}\right\rangle \right|\leq\Vert y_1-y_2\Vert_{2}\cdot\max_{z\in Z}\Vert Az\Vert_{2}
\end{multline*}
where the last inequality is by the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).
Since $\max_{z\in Z} \Vert A z \Vert_2$ is a constant independent of $y$, we have shown that $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) and hence continuous. $\Box$